# Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied. Counter after decrement: -1

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I use msiexec.msi line command to run a msi file created using WIX, the setup is runn with the parameter /qb and /promptrestart, but if I get the line 
"Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1"
in log the prompt didn't appear. The exit code of the msiexec process is 0 not 3010 (need restart) but the service that must be uninstalled remain in services.msc marked for deletion and some time even running (during install/uninstall services.msc is closed). 
After restart the computer all works fine.

Could you please tell me how to detect that a restart is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Installer is not very reliable when it comes to handling reboots. A good approach is to determine yourself if the install or uninstall process requires a reboot and trigger it manually if it does.

To perform a reboot you can use the [REBOOT property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371101%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to ensure the service isn't running through a custom action.